# Pulling headings from a String - Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

Just wondering, what would the best way for pulling information from headings in a String be.

I have a class and getter methods for the headings (Summary, Heading 1, Heading 2).

For example,

If I have a String equal to,

```
This: is the first line of a String: xx-string: This is a long String

Summary:
This is the summary of the String

Heading 1:
This is the first heading

Heading 2:
This is another heading
```

What would be a desirable way to set the value of the Strings,

Summary, Heading 1, Heading 2

to

```
Summary = This is the summary of the String
Heading 1 = This is the first heading
Heading 2 = This is another heading
```

Thanks !!

**Edit**

Here is what I was going for,

```
 public void setHeadings(Data fileData) {
        String description = fileData.getDescription();
        //String [] headings = description.split(":");

        int indexOf;
        indexOf = description.indexOf("Summary");
        if(indexOf != -1)
        {
            String subString = description.substring(indexOf);
            int indexOfNextHeading = subString.indexOf(":");
            if(indexOfNextHeading != -1)
            {
                System.out.println(indexOf + ":" + indexOfNextHeading);
                setSummary(description.substring(indexOf,indexOfNextHeading-1));
                System.out.println(description.substring(indexOf,indexOfNextHeading));
            }
        }
    }
```

That however, spits out an Array Out of bounds exception.

Comment: Are the summary and heading multi line paragraphs?  How about the first line?  Do we just drop that first line altogether?

Comment: Sounds like homework...?

Comment: Not homework, I'm an intern. The first box with the text in it is **one** String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Scanner object.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Then use it to read the String one line at a time.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(string);
sc.useDelimiter("\n");  // read one line at a time
```

Now sc.hasNext() tells you if there are lines left to read, and sc.next() returns the next line. Use this to iterate through the String one line at a time. You can test each line to see if it is equal to "Summary:" or "Heading 1:", etc. Then you can use a StringBuffer to add each line from each String you want to create.

I can write this for you if you want, but it's fairly simple.

Comment: I'm just trying this now, what should I do in a case where say, "Summary" has more than one line of information ? Like how do I know when to stop reading in lines for a particular heading ?

Comment: I would continue to append each line to the StringBuffer until you come to a line that shows you that it must have ended. If your format will always be "Summary: somelines Heading 1: somelines" then you can just go until you find a line equal to "Heading 1:".

Comment: Unfortunately that format won't always be the case, some of the headings may be absent.. any recommendations?

Comment: You just have to find some sort of flag that all the docs have in common that separate the different sections and look for that. Maybe there's always a blank line separating sections. Maybe lines only end in colons at the beginning of a section.